# How can I use py2neo to store a dictionary as one property value to single property key of a node in neo4j?

Tags: python, dictionary, neo4j, py2neo

I have a node and I want to add one property `property_x` whose value I want to be `{"year1":value, "year2":value}`. Making more than one node for each year is not needed as I need these values in my processing together.

Comment: Tried to edit but the question is very vague and needs more details if you hope it to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j only supports certain kinds of properties ([docs](http://www.neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-property-values)):

> ...there are restrictions as to what types of values can be used as
> property values. Allowed value types are as follows:
>
> - Numbers: Both integer values, with capacity as Java’s `Long` type, and floating points, with capacity as Java’s `Double`.
> - Booleans.
> - Strings.
> - Arrays of the basic types above.

You therefore cannot set a dictionary as a property. You could try using [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to convert the dictionary to a JSON string and storing the string. However, this will mean that you cannot easily use the content of the object when writing queries, and will need to `json.loads` the data back when you retrieve the node.

Alternatively, you could make the object a separate node with the properties `year1`, `year2`, etc., and link it to the first node with a relationship.