# Working with Python objects and Neo4j - ability to store objects such as pandas dataframes/dictionaries

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm working with a neo4j graph, using py2neo.

I understand that neo4j only [supports simple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025955/how-can-i-use-py2neo-to-store-a-dictionary-as-one-property-value-to-single-prope), but I have a use case where I need to store dictionaries and pandas dataframes with a large number of nodes.

For dictionaries I can encode the dictionary as json and store it as a Node property, i.e. `Node["dict"] = json.dumps(dict)`

and then `json.loads(dict)` to work with the dictionary when retrieving the node.

I could do the same with the pandas data frame (i.e. `Node["dict"] = json.dumps(df.to_dict())`), but it doesn't seem a particularly efficient way of doing it.

**Does anyone have suggestions on the best practice for working with a fairly large database of Python objects and neo4j? I'd like to be able to quickly access the Python objects from the neo4j database and work with/update them.**

Example below uses the simple `json.loads` approach as a starter.

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeMatcher, RelationshipMatcher
import json
import logging
import pandas as pd
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

db = Graph("bolt://192.168.X.X:7687", username = "XXX", password = "XXX")

class CurrentUser():
    def __init__(self, username, sender_id):
        # get node from database
        query = """MATCH (u:User) 
        WHERE u.SenderID = {} and u.UserName = "{}"
        RETURN u""".format(sender_id, username)
        self.user_node = db.evaluate(query)
        self.DF = pd.DataFrame()

    def add_dict(self, dict):
        self.user_node['dict'] = json.dumps(dict)
        db.push(self.user_node)

    def add_dataframe(self, s):
        self.DF = self.DF.append(s, ignore_index=False)
        self.user_node['df'] = json.dumps(self.DF.to_dict())
        db.push(self.user_node)


def create_nodes():
    query = """CREATE(u1:User {UserName: "Dave", SenderID: 10})"""
    db.run(query)

create_nodes()
user = CurrentUser("Dave", 10)
dict =  {"key": 10}
user.add_dict(dict)
pd_dict = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2}
s = pd.Series(pd_dict, name=2)
user.add_dataframe(s)
```